# DBIx::Class joins generate a large number of select statements

Tags: perl, join, dbix-class, prefetch

I've noticed that when I do a join in a select in DBIx::Class, I get a ton of SELECT statements as a result.  For instance, I have a query that looks like:

```
 my $testSetRs = $db->resultset('Testset')->search(
    {%searchCriteria},
    {
        prefetch  => [
            {
                'ax_group_testsets' => {'ax_group' => 'ax_user_groups'},
            },
            {'ax_user_testsets'  => 'ax_user'},
        ],
        '+columns' => [
            {
                'me.ax_group_testsets.ax_group_id'     => 'ax_group_testsets.ax_group_id',
                'me.ax_group_testsets.ax_group.public' => 'ax_group.public',
                'me.ax_group_testsets.ax_group.name'   => 'ax_group.name',
            },
        ],
        collapse => 1,
        group_by => ['me.ts_id', 'me.ts_name'],
        cache    => 1,
    }
);
```

generates:

```
SELECT me.ts_id, me.ts_name 
FROM testset me 
LEFT JOIN ax_group_testset ax_group_testsets ON ax_group_testsets.ts_id = me.ts_id 
LEFT JOIN ax_group ax_group ON ax_group.ax_group_id = ax_group_testsets.ax_group_id 
LEFT JOIN ax_user_group ax_user_groups ON ax_user_groups.ax_group_id = ax_group.ax_group_id 
LEFT JOIN ax_user_testset ax_user_testsets ON ax_user_testsets.ts_id = me.ts_id 
LEFT JOIN ax_user ax_user ON ax_user.ax_user_id = ax_user_testsets.ax_user_id 
WHERE ( ( ax_user.ax_user_id = ? OR ax_user_groups.ax_user_id = ? ) ) 
GROUP BY me.ts_id, me.ts_name: '349', '349'

SELECT me.ax_group_id, ax_group.public, ax_group.name FROM ax_group_testset me  JOIN ax_group ax_group ON ax_group.ax_group_id = me.ax_group_id WHERE ( me.ts_id = ? ): '4476'

SELECT me.ax_group_id, ax_group.public, ax_group.name FROM ax_group_testset me  JOIN ax_group ax_group ON ax_group.ax_group_id = me.ax_group_id WHERE ( me.ts_id = ? ): '4566'

SELECT me.ax_group_id, ax_group.public, ax_group.name FROM ax_group_testset me  JOIN ax_group ax_group ON ax_group.ax_group_id = me.ax_group_id WHERE ( me.ts_id = ? ): '4701'
```

etc.

The first SELECT, I want.  Its the ones that come after that bother me.  There is one for every group (over 40).  This happens on all of my joins and can jump into the hundreds with the right query.  Why are so many queries generated and what can I do about it?

I'm running Perl ActiveState 5.16 and DBIx .08250.

Comment: Are you sure the other SELECT statements don't result from code you execute after the first SELECT? It looks suspicious that `ax_group.public` is selected which has nothing to do with the initial query.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in the prefetch atribute as described in the [DBIx::Class::Manual::Joining](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aManual%3a%3aJoining#Whole-related-objects) and [DBIx::Class::ResultSet](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aResultSet#PREFETCHING) docs.

Add

```
  prefetch   => {'ax_group_testsets' => {'ax_group' => 'ax_user_groups'} },
```

and, assuming that you want all three related record columns:

```
  '+columns' => [ 
          { 
             'me.ax_group_testsets.ax_group_id'     => 'ax_group_testsets.ax_group_id',
             'me.ax_group_testsets.ax_group.public' => 'ax_group.public',
             'me.ax_group_testsets.ax_group.name'   => 'ax_group.name',
          },
      ],
   collapse => 1,
```

to the query attributes hash.

Comment: I think an explanation is in order here. I expect `prefetch` to *increase* the number of `SELECT` statements, not to decrease it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  From what I've read, prefetch is just another way to do a join.  I modified my query to use prefetch instead of join and the result is the same.  I get the primary query followed by a select statement for each group.

Comment: @Borodin, the prefetch fetches the extra data with the main select rather than waiting for you to explicitly request it. So if you only want 1% of the related rows it would be wasteful.

Comment: Since you're using the 'columns' attribute, you'll need to also include the columns form ax_gorup_testset in a '+columns' attribute. That way those columns will be prefetched.  As is is, because they're not mentioned in the first query, they're not retrieved and cached with the main table data, so DBIC has to go back in for them.

Comment: @Borodin prefetching causes the desired columns from related tables to  included (and returned) in the ResultSet's select, eliminating the need to make a subsequent database query for each row in the result. This is known as making 1+N queries and never preferable to making 1 query.

Comment: @RichardHuxton  In 25 years of working with RDBMSes, I have NEVER seen a situation where making N+1 round trips to the database was preferable to makeing 1 round trip to the DB where there was not a massive bug in the database's query optimzer.  I cannot think of a use case where I only need the related data 1% of the time that doesn't imply that I'm errantly selecting 99% of the retruned data.

Comment: @LenJaffe, couldn't agree more regarding building queries. However, this is an ORM we are dealing with and the code handling objects might not even know that it wants the related objects until after its started processing the data. DBIx::Class is better than most ORMs but they're all pretty dim regarding the difference in thinking between single items and set-wide processing.

Comment: @RichardHuxton - If your code does not know what data it needs from the database, then no amount of prefetching can help you. But in THIS CASE, the OP obviously wants the related data, and therefore N+1 queries is not the way to go about it.        I'll not debate the merits of ORMs with you because I seldom find them better then plain SQL once the joins get complex, which is really the whole point of the relational model.

Comment: @LenJaffe: I don't think it's obvious that the OP *"wants the related data"*. His question is clearly about how to avoid what he sees as superfluous `SELECT` calls.

Comment: @Borodin, but the extra SELECT calls are triggered when code tries to access the related data. If the result-set has defined relations you can just walk them and DBIx::Class will fetch the data on-the-fly. If he wasn't accessing the data there wouldn't be these SELECTs.

Comment: @RichardHuxton: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. The question implied that *all* of those `SELECT` calls were a result of the DBIC `search` call. Perhaps your explanation is the answer that the OP needs; he has been conspicuously silent through all of this discussion so who knows?

Comment: @LenJaffe: Thank you again for your patient advice.  I modified my sql to what is now up in the question.  I am still getting n+1 queries.  I'm at a loss.

Comment: Hmm. The +columns thing shoudl have made the query select those columns.  Would you be kind enough to show us the snippet of code that accesses the group name from the testset record?  That might help me understand a little better.

Comment: Try changing 'prefetch' to 'join', since prefetch implies join&+columns, but since your joins more then one level deep, you probably can't use prefetch (prefetch didn't work for me - 4 levels of FK relationships - request->pages->sections->fields) to I use join&+columns.  If that doesn't work, I'll post my code for comaparisson.